# Add record using datatables and dataadapter

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

How can I add records to a mysql database when I have a datatable and dataadapter? I can add data to the table but using the datatable.acceptchanges won't save the data into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `DataAdapter.Update` method.
You haven't provided any code sample, so I show you a pseudocode for this process..

```
 ' Create the adapter with a select command text to retrieve your records'
 Dim da = new MySqlDataAdapter(selecttext, connection)
 Dim table = new DataTable()
 da.Fill(table)

 ' Create a MySqlCommandBuilder to automatically generate the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands'
 Dim builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da)

 ' add the new rows to the table'
 Dim row = table.NewRow()
 .....
 table.Rows.Add(row)

 ' Send the changes to the database'
 ' do not call AcceptChanges before the Update'
 ' otherwise every row will be in the State Unchanged '
 ' and no changes will be saved to the database'
 da.Update(table)
```

You should remove the AcceptChanges call. This method is tricky. It doesn't try to update the database but it is used just to change the state of the changed or inserted row and remove the deleted rows from the in memory datatable.